# CKEditor 4.5.11 iframe IE11 permission denied

Tags: javascript, iframe, ckeditor

Sometimes on page load, i'm getting this error in CKEditor:

[image]

In src attribute written:

```
javascript:void(function(){document.open()%3B(%5Btype%20Function%5D)()%3Bdocument.close()%3B}())
```

[image]

Sorry for not English screenshots, i can translate them, if needed.

Comment: You ever have any luck resolving this? Im see the same issue with ie11 and ckeditor 4.5.8

Comment: I solved this problem with [divarea](http://ckeditor.com/addon/divarea) plugin